# HtmlDropdownlist which has option with multiple values

Tags: html-select

i want to create MVC razor  HtmlDropdownlist which has  option with multiple values
like option has name and class both attributes of student.

when i want to select dropdownlist both attributes appear same time.

### abc 123

dfg 456

Comment: can you give us a link with an example of this type of dropdown?

Comment: i am not to upload pic but it would be like                          abc 123
----------
dfg 456

Comment: Still not sure exactly what you're asking... do you mean a simple dropdown like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/LERTz/)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to extract these values from database you can concatenate the two fields as one and extract it to the list.. and finally show the list to dropdown..